# Quickblox - How to notify app when get income audio/video call, android platform?

Tags: android, quickblox, rtc

I have followed this official demo http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android.

I make a call from A to B. But if B is in SettingsActivity B can not receive the call. Wherever not in CallActivity, app in background, or do not open B can not receive incoming call too.

Any developers got this problem please help me? Many thanks.

Comment: Make a BaseActivity extends it with all your activities, and implement all the methods of QuickBlox in base activity. So when a call is received it will trigger as base activity is extended with all activity. try it and let me know

Comment: Thank you Rakshit Nawani. But in case the app is not open, how can I catch the incoming call? May I use the push notification as type calling (custom some kind of push notification), and when user tap on it, it starts call session? Could you write down some comments, please?

Comment: Yes I am also using the push notifications, when ever the call is hit send a push notification to opponent and check the type of the notification and then open the application directly, all the session will created and the Call will start with the opponent